# html form to add links and description to page

Tags: html, forms, hyperlink

I've got a simple basic .html document that I'm using for a "My Links.html" local, offline page to use as a way to store hyperlinks to other websites I find interesting.  It's kind of like a portable "bookmark" page on the go.  Here's some sample code that I've created already:

```
<b><h3>Web Design Resources</h3></b>
<hr />
<br />
<b><h4><u>CSS Tutorials</u></h4></b>

Line25.com
<ul>
<a href="http://line25.com/tutorials/" target="_blank">Tutorials</a>
 - main tutorials page<br />
<a href="http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu"     target="_blank">Pure CSS Dropdown</a>
 - Creating a dropdown menu solely out of css, nothing else (includes sub menus that slide out     to the right) <br />
<a href="http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-trendy-flat-style-nav-menu-in-css"    target="_blank">Trendy flat-style-css-menu</a>
 - how to create a trendy flat style css menu (hover over "menu image" puts menu title to the     right of the images)<br />
<a href="http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-slick-features-table-in-html-css"     target="_blank">Slick Features Comparison Table</a>
- a ghosted (semi transparent) table that vertically compares three items with the categories on    the left, box highlight on category font when hovering over any of the text in that row<br />
```

Simple Collapsing Header Effect
     - fixed horizontal menu on top with header text/image that is hidden when scrolling down the     page, replaced with the content

Currently I'm manually opening the html document and editing it to add each new link, description and categories (as they come up).

What I'm looking to do is add some simple forms and a submit button to update this offline .html document.  I'd like to keep everything contained in the one single document for ease of moving around.

Ideally it'd add text using this format:   "hyperlink - description"

With a dropdown of existing categories so that it adds to the correct section.  Just a couple text boxes, a dropdown box, and a submit link or button.  Nothing fancy, just the bare bones to "get the job done".

Thanks everyone, even if ya can just point me in the right direction or let me know the element names so I can more effectively research what I'm looking to do.

Comment: My understanding is that you want to append an html file using something available to html (jscript, css, html) on the client side.  This is impossible because what you're seeing is a copy of the html file, the actual html file is loaded by the browser into the dom, so even if you modify it there, the way it works is it won't update the html file.  You can however write something like a windows forms app to do it, or using a server language.  But the file cannot write onto itself in the manner you're describing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this will be possible with pure HTML.

You can alter the HTML with Javascript (jQuery) on the client side, but you won't be able to save the changes to your local file system trough Javascript. You can always save the altered document manually if that is an option, but it doesn't seem ideal to me.

For a more solid solution you would need some server side scripting like PHP, and a webserver like Apache running on your local machine (like XAMP or MAMP). And ideally you would need to work with some sort of database or XML file to store the data. Technically it is possible to just alter the HTML but it would be strange and highly uncommon. The XML file will be the easiest for portability, the database will be better for performance (and probably a more useful exercise).

Not sure if this is the best way to handle you 'problem' though. Why not just work with an existing service like [Xmarks](http://www.xmarks.com/). You will have access to your bookmarks directly from your browser, can sync them between various machines / browsers, or can access them through their website.

If you are just trying to learn something new however, I encourage the effort. Feel free to ask for any more specific pointers once you decided which route you want to take...